# getting Error ksh[7]: test: argument expected

Tags: shell

When executing the below line , am getting the `error ksh[7]: test: argument expected`

```
while [ $cont = "y" ]
```

Whats wrong with this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$cont` might not be set, which is why it fails.

Enclose the variable in double quotes like this:

```
while [ "$cont" = "y" ]
```

Comment: Its working fine now, after adding the double quotes as u suggested.Thanks a lot!!!